# Python: Unable to import Selenium using Jupyter

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've tried many different things to fix the problem, but when I use `from selenium import webdriver`, I always get `ImportError: No module named selenium`

Selenium is definitely installed in c:/Python27/Scripts using `pip install selenium` and also tried `-m pip install -U selenium`

Any suggestions? I've tried everything I could find on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ankur Singh answered my question. I needed to go run `conda install -c clinicalgraphics selenium` in an Anaconda Prompt window before importing Selenium

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using Python 3.7 and `pip install selenium --user` solved it for me.